# How do I call method from external library?

Tags: java, libraries, getter-setter

I just have a quick question my instructor didn't really go over. His examples aren't helping me.

```
 static double Q1(NormalDistribution distro, double x){
        // return the z-score of x in the given distribution
    }
```

It says to return the z-score of x in the given distribution. To not have to do all the math and "reinvent the wheel" each time, we are taught to import the library, I imported it, I'm just confused on how to call the class for the method. Please explain

**External Library**

```
    package cse115.math;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NormalDistribution{

    private double standardDeviation;
    private double mean;

    public NormalDistribution(double standardDeviation, double mean){
        this.standardDeviation = standardDeviation;
        this.mean = mean;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a normal distribution given a data set.
     */
    public NormalDistribution(ArrayList<Double> data){
        double sum = 0.0;
        for(double value : data){
            sum += value;
        }
        double mean = sum / data.size();
        double variance = 0.0;
        for(double value : data){
            variance += Math.pow(value - mean, 2.0);
        }
        variance /= data.size();

        this.mean = mean;
        this.standardDeviation = Math.sqrt(variance);
        // yes, this method puts 3 free points on the table for the observant.
    }


    /**
     * Returns the z-score of the provided value. Z-score is the number of standard deviations the value
     * is away from the mean.
     */
    public double zScore(double value){
        return (value - this.mean) / this.standardDeviation;
    }


    public double getStandardDeviation(){
        return this.standardDeviation;
    }

    public double getMean(){
        return this.mean;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "{" +
                "mean=" + mean +
                ", standardDeviation=" + standardDeviation +
                '}';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to create an instance of the external class within your main method.

```
    NormalDistribution normalDistribution = new NormalDistribution(0,0);
```

you will then call the static function Q1 through the Classname which holds it, passing the NormalDistribution and the double x.

```
    double value = Cse115.Q1(normalDistribution,1);
```

Whatever those are supposed to do is up to you, good luck.